# PHP changing individual table cell values

Tags: php, sql, html-table

I'm making a web application using PHP. I'm generating a table with a SQL database. What I need to do is change the value of individual cells when I click on the button next to the cell. The values I put in the textbox need to be sent to the database. The problem is that when I press a button every value gets sent in stead of the individual one. I'm giving each textbox an individual id.

Here's my code:

```
<table id="Aanbodstabel">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width = 8%>Fustcode</th>
            <th width = 8%>Cultivar</th>
            <th width = 8%>Fust</th>
            <th width = 8%>Aantal p. Fust</th>
            <th width = 8%>Aanbod</th>
            <th width = 2%>Bestellen</th>
            <th width = 8%>AantalBesteld</th>
            <th width = 10%></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $AanbodsTabel = (BestellingDB::getInstance()->get_aanbod_per_datum_per_gebruikersid($GebruikersID));

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($AanbodsTabel)){
            echo "<tr><td width = 6%>Fustcode</td>";
            echo "<td width = 6%>" . htmlentities($row['cultivar']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td width = 6%>" . htmlentities($row['AantalFust']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td width = 6%>" . htmlentities($row['AantalPerFust']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td width = 6%>" . htmlentities($row['AantalStelen']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td width = 4%><input type ='text' id='Bestelbox' value='' name='AantalBestellen " . htmlentities($row['aanbodid']) . "' </td>";
            echo "<td width = 6%>" . htmlentities($row['AantalFust']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td width = 8%><input type='submit' value='Bestellen' name='btnBestellen' class='btnBestel'/></td></tr>";
        }
        mysqli_free_result($AanbodsTabel);
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
```

If any other code is needed I'm  happy to post it.

Comment: One soloution would be to move the form tags inside the loop so that each input group get their own form / submit. Also, ID's need to be unique and you seem to be missing a `>` in your input text field.

Comment: Haha thanks for the missing > and the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `submit` in a form, if you want to send the individual value. When use submit, it will submit the entire form.

For example you can use individual url to replace the `submit` elemnt. For example:

`echo '<td width = 8%><a href="http://yoururl?cultivar='.$cultivar.'&AantalPerFust='.$AantalPerFust.'">Button</a></td></tr>';`

Comment: Thanks, your solution gives me each individual cell and adds the right values! The only thing I needed to change is $cultivar into htmlentities($row['cultivar'].

Comment: How do I pass the values from the textbox into the URL?